# Cell data not padding?

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything,

```
<table cellspacing="10"></table>
```

and have tried to do it in the css as well:

```
td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Nothing seems to be working. I have no idea how to fix this, and have been trying for about 2 hours. Please help. Thank you. Here is a link to the problematic web page.

http://s1527.mtchs.org/wordpress/fees/

Comment: that's not even close to proper html/css

Comment: I just posted the code that wasn't working. that isn't my entire web page.

Comment: You should post a more accurate snippet of code. The way you have it as of now it is very misleading and makes it more difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stylesheet rule

```
.calendar-table table, tbody, tr, td {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

You need a selector with higher specificity in the author important stylesheet in order to override this.  You should probably just remove that other rule, or just replace it with `padding: 10px`

Comment: thanks so much! I feel so dumb for such a simple error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction

```
<style type="text/css">
 td {
  padding: 10px;
 }
</style>
<table cellspacing="10">
 <tr>
  <td>some text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

1. CSS rules go in the the `<style>` tag ( typically in the `<head>` of the document)
2. The "C" in CSS stands for cascading. Make sure other rules don't override it. (See Explosion Pills' answer for more on that).
3. Mozilla has a good [kickstart for learning CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

For a better HTML and CSS, I recommend you to wrap the values inside the table in `span` elements. This way you can achieve your results and you don't need tricky CSS.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class='my-fancy-cell'>$1</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and give the `span` a class and the CSS you need. This is not only cleaner but also an elegant solution.

```
my-fancy-cell {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The alternatives you have (what you see in other answers) are:

- `border-spacing` CSS rule
- `important!` CSS directive
- `box-sizing` CSS rule
- `display` CSS rule

(or a combination of them)

Comment: I don't think what they're looking for is tricky. Plus this makes the code unnecessarily more complex and bulky.